# what is API Limit for IBM cloud storage object S3 API?

Tags: api, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I need information about API limit of IBM cloud storage object S3 API.I have gone through all the information available on https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/ but unable to any information related to API limit.Please provide details or any reference to get details on this.

Comment: Why don't you ask IBM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no enforced limit to the number of API requests made to IBM COS.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about number of operations or storage volume? I'm not aware of any limit for either. I do believe a minimum object size of 128kb applies as part of the capacity usage charge though.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: API limit is something about API requests which we can make on Per Day or Per User or Per Application basis like for Zoho CRM API, it has been mentioned in url " https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/api-limits.html "

Comment: Ah OK. I don't think there is a limit. I haven't seen anything that would suggest otherwise. As far as I know IBM doesn't have different subscription levels. They just charge for what you use. That being the case it wouldn't make sense to have an upper limit. I could be wrong though.